# Many Markov chains with one graph

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am studying Markov chain as a beginner. When I read some documents, I often find a sentence as follows.

"For an undirected graph, many finite irreducible Markov chains can be generated."

But, it is difficult for me to imagine some examples for the sentence. Could you please give a simple example that explains the sentence above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a connected graph and think of a simple random walk on it. This means that at any given vertex, you go to a neighbouring one with equal probability. This is also called the drunkard's walk, since it is like a drunk person stumbling randomly at each time. Thus you can create the probability transition matrix and think of it as Markov chain since at any given moment, how you move is not affected by past movements. Since the graph is connected, you can reach any given point so it is also irreducible.

Comment: Then, the following two cases can be two MCs for the graph of your example? Case1) t=0 : A (a drunk person is at location A at time 0)  ==> t=1 : B ==> t=2 ......, and Case2) t=0 : B ==> t=1 : A ==> t=2 : ....... . Thanks.

Comment: Well you need to assign probabilities for the movement. If you only have a graph of two points, it will go back and forth all the time. But for example, imagine 5 points, a,b,c,d,e in a straight line. Then at any given point you have 50% chance of going left or right. So you would have a Markov Chain with 5 states and a 5x5 transition probability matrix that has zeros, 0.5 and 1 for $p_{ab}, p_{ed}$ where these are the probabilities of going from a to b and from e to d respectively.